# create a dropdown list with links in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

i would like to create a dropdown list, which the options there will be links, i didnt find a simple way of doing it.
Can someone maybe put a little example of how it can be done ?

Thanks

Comment: So the result is you want there to be a drop down and when you click it, it's actually a link, so it goes to some controller action? You can do this with JS watching the options being clicked (but still using a normal select element), or go the route of making a drop down yourself using DIVs.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a real simple dropdown using jquery `slideToggle()`.You can convert the html to haml or erb or whatever you're using for rails

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown").slideToggle();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LrAfm/)